# Связь @ManyToMany 3 таблиц

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Имеются таблицы `dish, kitchen, restaraunt` и общая таблица `many` которая имеет в себе все поля таблиц `dish, kitchen, restaraunt`, поскольку только начал изучать hibernate , не могу понять как именно связать все три таблицы с `many`

Вкратце о связи, ресторан имеет блюдо, блюдо могут иметь много ресторанов
Ресторан имеет кухню, кухню имеет много ресторанов

**Kitchen model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kitchen")
public class Kitchen {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_photo")
    private Blob photo;
}
```

**Dish model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dish")
public class Dish {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "dish_name")
    private String dishName;
    @Column(name = "dish_photo")
    private Blob dishPhoto;
```

**Restaraunt model**

```
 public class Restaraunt {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;
        @Column(name = "res_name")
        private String name;
        @Column(name = "res_rating")
        private double rating;
        @Column(name = "res_address")
        private String address;
        @Column(name = "res_number")
        private String number;
        @Column(name = "res_site")
        private String site;
        @Column(name = "res_price")
        private String price;
        @Column(name = "res_photo")
        private Blob photo;
```

Ну и общая таблица с которой все нужно связать
**Many Model**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "res_id")
    private long res_id;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_id")
    private long kitchen_id;
    @Column(name = "dish_id")
    private long dish_id;
    @Column(name = "many_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "many_rating")
    private double rating;
    @Column(name = "many_address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "namy_number")
    private String number;
    @Column(name = "many_site")
    private String site;
    @Column(name = "many_price")
    private String price;
    @Column(name = "many_photo")
    private Blob photo;
    @Column(name = "dish_name")
    private String dishName;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_name")
    private String kitchenName;
    @Column(name = "dish_photo")
    private Blob dishPhoto;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_photo")
    private Blob kitchePhoto;
```

Понимаю , что нужно связать через @ManyToMany но как прописать если честно - затрудняюсь :(

Comment: А что за общая таблица? Для какой цели она предназначена?

Comment: @FirstSin для вывода общей информации по ресторану (кухня, блюда, фото кухни, фото блюда и т.п.)

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно в каждом `Entity` сделать 2 `ManyToMany` связи

Кухня

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kitchen")
public class Kitchen {
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "kitchen_dish",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "kitchen_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id") }
    )
    private List<Dish> dishs = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "kitchen_restaurant",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "kitchen_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id") }
    )
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Ресторан

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant {
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "restaurant_dish",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id") }
    )
    private List<Dish> dishs = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "kitchen_restaurant",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "kitchen_id") }
    )
    private List<Kitchen> kitchens = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Блюдо

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dish")
public class Dish {
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "restaurant_dish",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id") }
    )
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "kitchen_dish",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "kitchen_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id") }
    )
    private List<Kitchen> kitchens = new ArrayList<>();
}
```